# Alt-backspace working on Cygwin/mintty?

Tags: cygwin, mintty

I am not quite sure what happened ... alt-backspace won't backward-kill-word any more in my Cygwin install. It looks like I did an update on 7/17/2013, not sure what was in the update, I usually just pull whatever's the latest version of the modules I have.

Backspace itself works, it's with the alt that nothing happens. I tried both right and left alt keys.

I couldn't figure out where to start here - I didn't change anything in my Mintty settings, or in my .inputrc at all. I'm at a total loss...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, never mind. I just had to restart my laptop. And the problem's gone.